# How to develop with phonegap/cordova on a raspberry pi2?

Tags: cordova, raspberry-pi2

I would like to develop apps with phonegap/cordova on a raspberry pi 2.
I am looking for a programming/development tool to do so (something like the Arduino IDE for the Arduino platform). I am new to Javascript and not very firm in HTML5, but I know C and Python.

Comment: Your question is tooooo wide. Change it to one single problem.

Comment: Edited my question, hope you can get what I am asking for.

Comment: maybe this would be helpful: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/03/home-automation-with-angularjs-and-node-js-on-a-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Sorry but no. I need something like an IDE or a very powerful editor, to code, debug and run the code.

Comment: I know two IDEs for Cordova, which have Raspberry support - Visual Studio 2015 and Intel XDK HTML. Of course there's also aptana Studio but I don't know how it works with Rasp/Adruino

Comment: Visual Studio will not run on a Pi. I do not know if Aptana Studio will.